# :before and background-image... should it work?

Tags: css, background-image

I've got a div and apply `:before` and `:after` an image as content. That works perfectly. Now I would need to apply a background image so it does repeat as the `div` resizes, but it does not seem to work. Is background image on `:before` and `:after` supposed to be working?

The current code:

HTML:

```
<div id="videos-part">test</div>
```

CSS:

```
#videos-part{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 127px;
    width: 764px;
    margin: -6px 0 -1px 18px;
    position: relative;
}
#videos-part:before{
    width: 16px;
    content: " ";
    background-image: url(/img/border-left3.png);
    position: absolute;
    left: -16px;
    top: -6px;
}
```

Comment: Paste your code into your question.

Comment: Updated the question with my code

Comment: My problem was missing `content`. It needs to have some content to apply the background.

Comment: Thanks @Neolisk... important detail :-)

Comment: Yeah but you can't apply hover effect on it then.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

@michi; define `height` in your `before` pseudo class

CSS:

```
#videos-part:before{
    width: 16px;
    content: " ";
    background-image: url(/img/border-left3.png);
    position: absolute;
    left: -16px;
    top: -6px;
    height:20px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep... I can't use height as the div will resize depending on its content.

Comment: Hmm... I just tried to put the height and the background image appears :-( Will I really have to use JS to change the height dynamically?

Comment: I just added height: 100% and it works :-) Stupid me that I haven't thought of it before. Thanks very much Sandeep :-)

Comment: This wouldn't work for me using background-color. Had to use background: #295b79 url('../images/image.png') no-repeat;

Answer (score 8):

Background images on `:before` and `:after` elements should work. If you post an example I could probably tell you why it does not work in your case.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/namas/3/

You can specify the dimensions of the element in % by using `background-size: 100% 100%` (width / height), for example.

Comment: Hi Meo, I've updated my question with the code I'm using. Thanks for helping :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
 color: transparent;
```

make the tricks for me

```
#videos-part:before{
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 33px;
    width: 16px;
    color: transparent;
    content: 'AS YOU LIKE';
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
    background-size: 25px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with other answers here is that they use `position: absolute;`

This makes it difficult to layout the element itself in relation to the `::before` pseudo-element. For example, if you wish to show an image before a link like this:
[image]

Here's how I was able to achieve the layout in the picture:

```css
a::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: url(../../lhsMenu/images/internal_link.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 80%;
}
```

Note that this method allows you to scale the background image, as well as keep the ability to use margins and padding for layout.

Answer (score 3):

you can set an image URL for the content prop instead of the background-image.

```
content: url(/img/border-left3.png);
```

*This itself wont solve everything. Need to consider repeat, size, position etc using other properties.*

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, I need [`float`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) property of a pseudo-element to be set to `left` or `right` for the image to appear. `height` and `width` of the pseudo-element should be both set but not in percentage. I'm on Firefox 67.